# Polynomial Functions (Thinking #1; High school math)

Tags: functions, polynomials

Question: Consider the polynomial function: $2x^3 - mx^2 + x -5m$. The remainder when $P(x)$ is divided by $(x - 2)$ is four times the remainder from dividing $P(x)$ by $(x + 1)$. Determine $m$ algebraically and show all your work.

I tried to do this on my own and I managed to find the remainder and the quotient using the function $2x^3 - mx^2 + x -5m$ with the dividend, $(x - 2)$ and $(x + 1)$. (I got two remainders and the two quotients) but now I don't know what to do next and how to solve for $m$.

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me solve this question! Thanks.

Comment: By the polynomial remainder theorem you just need to equate $P(2)$ with $4P(-1)$.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [polynomial remainder theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) states that the remainder of the division of a polynomial $f(x)$ by the linear polynomial $x-r$ is equal to $f(r)$.

So in your case, the remainder when $P(x)$ is divided by $(x-2)$ is $P(2)$, and the remainder when $P(x)$ is divided by $(x+1)$ is $P(-1)$ (as $x+1=x-(-1)$).

It is given that the remainder after division by $(x-2)$ is four times the remainder after division by $(x+1)$. So, using the above, $P(2)$ is four times $P(-1)$, or
$$P(2)=4P(-1)$$
which means that you need to solve
$$2(2)^3-m(2)^2+2-5m=4[2(-1)^3-m(-1)^2+(-1)-5m]$$
to find $m$.